# How do I know which value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html:

```
 <p class="form-row " id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field">
           <label>Radio</label>
           <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male" class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Male" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male">Male</label>
           <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female" class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Female" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female">Female</label>
    </p>
```

I need to know if the value selected is male or female. I could do by this but the like this but id is different

```
    jQuery("#radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field").on('change', function(){
       var value = this.value;
       if( value === 'Female' ) { 
        alert('succcess');
     }
   });
```

If I could get the value through name it would be simpler like:

```
jQuery("radio_xsdfYxsfWEx").on('change', function(){
       var value = this.value;
       if( value === 'Female' ) { 
        alert('succcess');
     }
   });
```

But, both failed, What is appropriate way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work , you need to use the value of the target , the example is close to your code

```js
jQuery("#radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field").on('change', function(e){
       if( e.target.value === 'Female' ) { 
        alert('succcess');
     }
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row " id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field">
           <label>Radio</label>
           <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male" class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Male" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male">Male</label>
           <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female" class="radio">
                <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Female" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female">Female</label>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cheked radio input value using this : 
`$("input[name='radio_xsdfYxsfWEx']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 1):

Just get the `.val()` (value) of the group during the `change` event.

```js
$("input[name='radio_xsdfYxsfWEx']").on("change", function(){
  let val = $(this).val(); // Get the value of the group
  
  // Do what you want with the value
  console.log(val);
  if(val === "Female") {
    alert("Success!");
  } else {
    alert("Failure");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-row " id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field">
  <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Male" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male">Male</label>
  <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female" class="radio">
  <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Female" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female">Female</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Attribute selectors and `:checked` help:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("input")].forEach(e => e.addEventListener("change", () =>
    console.log(document.querySelector("[name=radio_xsdfYxsfWEx]:checked").value)
));
```

```html
 <p class="form-row " id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_field">
       <label>Radio</label>
       <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male" class="radio">
            <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Male" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Male">Male</label>
       <label for="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female" class="radio">
            <input type="radio" class="input-radio um-field" value="Female" name="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx" id="radio_xsdfYxsfWEx_Female">Female</label>
</p>
```

<sub>(Furthermore, i believe that jQuery should never be used.)</sub>

Comment: i totaly agree about the fact that Jquery should be avoided